# Get value of a select element with ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm trying to get a value of a select element, but is returning `Array()`

This is my html:

```
<select name="data[Attorney][empresa]" id="AttorneyEmpresa">
    <option value="">Selecione</option>
    <option value="3">Sotreq</option>
</select>
```

And my Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#AttorneyEmpresa").change(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            data: $('#AttorneyEmpresa').val()
        });
    });
});
```

What's wrong?

Comment: You should send a `key:value` pair for the POST method.

Comment: *Where* does it return `Array()`?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#AttorneyEmpresa").change(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            data:  {keyname:$('#AttorneyEmpresa option:selected').val()}
        });
    });
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/a5gkq/)

Answer (score 3):

The data attribute should be Object type like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#AttorneyEmpresa").change(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            data:  { "select" : $('#AttorneyEmpresa').val()}

        })
    })
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to send the day as an object.

```
var data = { somekey: $('#AttorneyEmpresa').val() }
```